# Accessing variable from different class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to access the state variable `testState` from the different class `UserAuthentication`?

I have tried this without success:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserAuthenticationUI from './UserAuthentication/UserAuthenticationUI';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.userAuthenticationUI = React.createRef();
    this.state={
      testState: 'test message'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <UserAuthenticationUI ref={this.userAuthenticationUI} />
      <div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

How to access `this.state.teststate` from class `UserAuthenticationUI`?

```
import React from "react";
import App from '../App';

class UserAuthenticationUI extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.app = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <App ref={this.app} />
          {console.log(this.state.testState)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserAuthenticationUI;
```

Comment: In theory you can use Classname.state.statename BUT there are not many cases where I would recommend this approach. -> In your case I would recommend to use props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it via props.

```
import React from "react";
import UserAuthenticationUI from "./UserAuthentication/UserAuthenticationUI";

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.userAuthenticationUI = React.createRef();
        this.setParentState = this.setParentState.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          testState: "test message"
        };
      }
      setParentState(newStateValue){ // this is called from the child component
          this.setState({
              testState: newStateValue
          })
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <UserAuthenticationUI
              stateVariable={this.state.testState}
              ref={this.userAuthenticationUI}
              setParentState={this.setParentState}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

UserAuthenticationUI:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "../App";

class UserAuthenticationUI extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.app = React.createRef();
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick(){
      const newStateValue = 'new parent state value';
      if(typeof this.props.setParentState !== 'undefined'){
        this.props.setParentState(newStateValue);
      }
  }
  render() {
    const stateProps = this.props.stateVariable;
    return (
      <div>
        <App ref={this.app} />
        <div onClick={this.onClick} />
        {console.log(stateProps)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserAuthenticationUI;
```

Comment: How to set state?

Comment: You can pass a callback function as a prop from parent to child to set a state in the parent from a child component. @Bobek

Comment: can you write an example please?

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the same. Assuming App as Parent and UIComponent as child component. @Bobek

Comment: when adding  <App ref={this.app} /> into child app freeze on loading

Answer (score 0):

You should think differently.

Try to read the variable via GET methods and set via SET methods.
Do not try to call the variable immediately

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it through **Props**:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserAuthenticationUI from 
'./UserAuthentication/UserAuthenticationUI';

      class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);


            this.userAuthenticationUI = React.createRef();

           this.state={

               testState: 'test message'
               }
        }

    render(){
    return(
    <div>
    <UserAuthenticationUI testState={this.state.testState} />
    <div>
        )}
    }
    export default App;
```

**UserAuthenticationUI:**

```
   import React from "react";
   import App from '../App';

     class UserAuthenticationUI extends React.Component 
    {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);


        }

        render(){
    return(
       <div>
            <App/>
            {console.log(this.props.testState)}
      </div>
    )}
    }

    export default UserAuthenticationUI;
```

Comment: How to set state in App from UserAuthenticationUI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via props:

```
<div>
   <UserAuthenticationUI testState={this.state.testState} ref={this.userAuthenticationUI} />
<div>
```

and in UserAuthenticationUI class access it:

```
  <div>
        <App ref={this.app} />
        {console.log(this.props.testState)}
  </div>
```